# Make Background Slideshow Images Individually Clickable

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a background image slideshow for my photography portfolio.
When each image fades in, I want it to link to its respective gallery.
I also have a text box that fades with the images. I would like to also link to the respective gallery. I have not added the code in for that yet as I do not know how without ruining all the code linked to the .
At the moment, no matter where I seem to put the links, they overlap and the bottom (link3) is only clickable.

My HTML:

```
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
<li>
    <span><a id="gallerylink" href="link1"></a></span> 
    <div>
        <h3>Fire &amp; Light</h3>
    </div>
</li>
<li> 
<span><a id="gallerylink" href="link2"></a></span> 
    <div>
        <h3>Live Music</h3> 
    </div>
</li>
<li> 
<span><a id="gallerylink" href="link3"></a></span> 
    <div>
        <h3>Water &amp; Nature</h3> 
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
#gallerylink { 
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
background-color: transparent;
z-index: 999;
}
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 0; 
list-style-type: none;
}
.cb-slideshow li span  { 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
color: transparent;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: none;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 0;
animation: imageAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
bottom: 5%;
right:5%;
width: 10%;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0;
color: #fff;
animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 { 
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 2px;
padding: 0;
background-color: white;
line-height: 45px; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
background-image: url(iamge1)
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
background-image: url(image2);
animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
background-image: url(image3);
animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
animation-delay: 12s; 
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
5% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
30% { opacity: 1 }
35% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0 }
5% { opacity: 1 }
30% { opacity: 1 }
33% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
.cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 20px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
.cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 14px }
}
```

FYI I'm not taking credit for most of this code; its from: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/

I realise the background-image and a href 's are not real links. I removed them so it would allow me to post this question with low reputation.
Here is the page in question if that helps: http://kalemhornphoto.format.com/
This particular site runs off Format, which takes care of my site theme (and code) hosting and backend, though my CSS and HTML overrides theirs.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is one way:

```
// Go trough every li with #gallerylink inside
$("li #gallerylink").each(function()
{
    // Bind click event to it
    $(this).parent().on("click", function()
    {
        // Click the link if the li is clicked
        $(this).find("#gallerylink")[0].click();
    });
});
```